# limit function to only work with argument from a specific instance

Tags: python

I have a function and I want the first positional argument   of that only give the instances of a specific class  , 
a code like this in other programming languages

```
from channels import Channel


def get_frame_link(Channel channel):
    print(channel)
```

if coder use that function in this way the python most raise an error

```
get_frame_link(123)
get_frame_link("hello")
```

the truth way most be only this

```
channel=Channel()
get_frame_link(channel)
```

note: this is not duplicated question because  I don't asked for how to check a variable type

Comment: well you did basically asked how to check a variable's type as there is no other way to "block" Python from accepting any type as an argument... You have type-hints, but those are just helpers and the user can still do whatever he wants

Answer (score 1):

Simply check that the type matches what you desire:

```
def get_frame_link(channel):
    if not isinstance(channel, Channel):
        raise TypeError("instance of type Channel expected")

    print(channel)
```